# Получить имя класса кнопки на которую кликнули Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='button' class='met1' value='vvod' /><br>
<input type='button' class='met2' value='vvod' /><br>
<input type='button' class='met2' value='vvod' /><br>
```

Собственно сами кнопки я генерирую через `php` что-то типа:
`btn1`, `btn2` и т.д.
В файле `js` описываю следующую вещь:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on("click",function(){
        alert($(this).attr("class"));
  });
});
```

Ну и ничего не работает...
Может есть какой-то простой способ сделать так, чтобы кнопки работали (не хочется 10 кнопок писать)?

Ну а имя класса я хотел получить, чтобы вытащить из него номер кнопки после чего кинуть в `ajax` запрос.

Или может есть у кого-то идеи получить номер кнопок как-то иначе, буду благодарен любой помощи, спасибо !

Comment: Все работает. Что значит "ничего не работает"? Маленький гномик вылезает из компьютера и говорит: "Ничего не работает"?

Comment: Ну если бы все работало я бы сюда не писал.

Comment: Создайте "неработающий" пример с помощью кнопки "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас элемент называется `input`, а вы ищете `$('button')`. Нужно поменять либо одно либо другое.

Comment: 2 часа ночи, я спать )) спасибо, поменял на input[type=button] все заработало.